# Replace some strings in files with specific extensions using `sed`

Tags: linux, sed, sh

Speicifcally, I have a list of include directives: `xxx/A.h`, `xxx/B.h`, `xxx/C.h`...

I want to replace all the occurences of `"xxx/X.h"` with `<xxx/X.h>` in all `.h`, `.c` and `.cpp` files in a directory.

I tried this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

name="xxx/A.h"

# This command successfully replaces "xxx/A.h" with <xxx/A.h> in A.cpp
sed -i "s;\"$name\";\<$name\>;g" A.cpp

# This command doesn't work. I need something like this to change the occurrences in all *.cpp, *.c files
find . -type f -a \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -a -exec sed -i "s;\"$name\";\<$name\>;g" {} +
```

Why the second command doesn't work? How should I do this?

Comment: How does it not work? If you remove the final `-exec`, does it print the correct files? `-a` is not necessary, by the way, it's implied.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry so much. It turned out the reason is that `sed` stops when it processes some files without permissions and those files expected to be processed are not processed. This command works actaully.

Answer (score -1):

It turned out the reason is that sed stops when it processes some files without permissions and those files expected to be processed are not processed.